# PowerDesigner Possibility to drop tables when "Apply Model Changes to Database"

Tags: powerdesigner

when generating a database in PowerDesigner I have the option to drop all Tables/Tablespaces and so on before generating the Database: [Option to Select](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUfE8.png)

But this Option isnt there when applying changes to a database. I need this, because some local databases could already have some of the Changes I made to the model and I cant drop all tables because of the data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question, when you are ready to drop some tables instead of modifying them, but you don't want to drop **all** tables.

It seems to me that you could use `Database > Apply Model Changes to Database` with the `Connect to a Data Source` to compare the model with an existing database, and just generate the necessary modification scripts.

Maybe you could use a saved Selection to generate an Alter Script for most tables, and another to generate a Drop+Create script for some "transient" tables.